# Sending email using GMail account

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have written java code for send mail which is giving exception : when i use port number 465

> com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 l1sm2119061pbe.54

```
import java.util.*; 
import javax.mail.*; 
import javax.mail.internet.*; 
import javax.activation.*; 

String USERNAME = username; 
String PASSWORD = password; 


Properties props = new Properties(); 
props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost); 
if(smtpPort != null){
    int SMTP_PORT = Integer.parseInt(smtpPort); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT); 
}
props.put("mail.from",from);
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
if( auth == 1){
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
}
props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() { 
        @Override 
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
            return new PasswordAuthentication(USERNAME, PASSWORD); 
        } 
}); 

MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 
msg.setFrom(); 
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to); 
msg.setSubject(subject); 
msg.setSentDate(new Date());

Multipart content = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

bodyPart.setText(htmlBody, "UTF-8");
bodyPart.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html");

content.addBodyPart(bodyPart);

if ( attachmentPath != null ){
    String[] a = attachmentPath.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 
            if( a[i] != null )
        {
            MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            attachmentPart.attachFile(a[i].trim());
            content.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
        }
    }
}


msg.setContent(content);

Transport.send(msg); 
return true
```

Comment: SM_SendEmail( from ; to ; subject ; htmlBody ; attachmentPath ; smtpHost ; smtpPort ; SSL ; TLS ; auth ; username ; password ): This is method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is self explanatory, this is a working code that i used in a project. Hope this help you out. Good Luck.

```
/**
 GmailSmtpSSL emailNotify = new GmailSmtpSSL(cred[ID], cred[PASS]);

 emailNotify.sendMailTo("self","Testing AlfaDX Gmail module", "Yes it works");

**/

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class GmailSmtpSSL {

    GmailSmtpSSL(String username,String password) {
        usern = username;
        pass  = password;

        setDebugMsg("Setting user name to : "+usern);
        setDebugMsg("Using given password : "+pass);

        props = new Properties();
        setDebugMsg("Setting smtp server: smtp.gmail.com");
        setDebugMsg("Using SSL at port 465 auth enabled");

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", usern);

        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        //props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");

        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        SMTPAuthenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
        session.setDebug(true);
        setDebugMsg("Session initialization complete");
    }

    public void destroy() {
        props.clear();
        props = null;
        usern = null;
        pass  = null;
        session = null;

    }

    public void sendMailTo(String to, String sub, String body)
                                                    throws MessagingException {

         Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
         SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a"); 
         String dateToday = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime()).toLowerCase();

         if (to.equals("self")) 
             to = usern;

         setDebugMsg("Composing message: To "+to);
         setDebugMsg("Composing message: Subject "+sub);

         try {
             Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(usern));
             message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, 
                                                    InternetAddress.parse(to));
             message.setSubject("PinguBot: "+dateToday+" "+sub);
             message.setText(body);
             setDebugMsg("Attempting to send...");
             Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");

             transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, usern, pass);
             Transport.send(message);
             transport.close();
         }

         catch(MessagingException me) {
             setDebugMsg(me.toString());
             throw new MessagingException(me.toString());
         }
             setDebugMsg("Mail was send successfully");
    }


    public String getDebugMsg() {
        String msg = new String(debugMsg);
        debugMsg = " ";
        return msg;
    }
    private static void setDebugMsg(String msg) {
        debugMsg += msg + "\n";
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    private static String debugMsg = "";
    private String usern; 
    private String pass;
    private Session session;
    private static Properties props;

    private class SMTPAuthenticator extends Authenticator
    {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(usern, pass);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Before testing this code. don't bother about the errors that you found in your code. The both codes are totally different. Just try this out.

Answer (score 0):

> when i use port number -1

Hardly surprising. -1 isn't a valid port number. What happens when you use a *correct* port number?

> when i use port number 465

That's not a standard SMTP port either.

What happens when you use the *correct* port number?

Comment: when I use 465 then it give same Exception: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 l1sm2119061pbe.54

Comment: Standard or not, Gmail uses 465 as the SMTP port for SSL: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Comment: @EliAcherkan Good so it should work perfectly then ... as long as he uses SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code that authenticates and sends mails to Gmail server using `javax.mail`. Take care of firewall and the host port you selected.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;

final class MailClient
{
    private class SMTPAuthenticator extends Authenticator
    {
        private PasswordAuthentication authentication;

        public SMTPAuthenticator(String login, String password)
        {
             authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(login, password);
        }

        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
             return authentication;
        }
    }

    public void mail()
    {
        try
        {
            String from = "xyz.com";
            String to = "abc.com";
            String subject = "Your Subject.";
            String message = "Message Text.";
            String login = "xyz.com";
            String password = "password";

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator(login, password);

            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

           try
           {
                msg.setText(message);
                msg.setSubject(subject);
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(to));
                Transport.send(msg);
           }
           catch (MessagingException ex)
           {
                Logger.getLogger(MailClient.class.getName()).
                log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
        }
    }
}

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        new MailClient().mail();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can separate and use the attachment part from your code and use it along with this code.